# Hibernate: How to set the value of a custom UserType

Tags: hibernate, blob, hibernate-mapping, clob, usertype

I've got a ClobType that extends Hibernate's UserType and does about what you'd expect:  converts the clob found in the database to a String.  I mapped my clob columns to the ClobType, and those columns render nicely when I access them in my JSP pages.

But now that I'm trying to set the value, I'm stumped.  Because I can write `${myObject.longField}` in my JSP pages tells me I can probably say

```
String s = myObject.getLongField().toString();
```

and get the string, despite the fact that LongField is of type ClobType.

What I don't know is how to use the setter.  I can instantiate a ClobType easily, but how do I give it string data that it needs to persist as a blob?

```
ClobType clobType = new ClobType();
String s = "... a really REALLY long string ...";
/* a miracle occurs */
myObject.setLongField( clobType );
myObjectDAO.saveOrUpdate( myObject );
```

What is the miracle I need in order to give the ClobType a string value?

Or, is there a better (or more proper) way of having my two setters return Strings rather than ClobTypes?  Is there a special mapping that does this?  My business logic has no need to know that a given column is implemented as a blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you're using a reasonably current hibernate, you can map a java String to a database CLOB without using a custom `UserType` at all.

Try

```
@Lob
public String getLongField() { return longField; }
```

with longField just a `String`.

If this works, it'll be much simpler than what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  But I'm not using annotations, and I don't know how to "translate" that.

Comment: There may be a way to do it with xml as well, but I don't know the translation either right off.

Comment: You know what?  I was accidentally doing this the "right" way all along.  When I re-generated my pojos from my mapping files today, my tests on these clob fields broke.  The reason was that the mapping was there, but the POJOs had those fields defined as Strings.  And Hibernate just sorta magically handles it.

Comment: And now that I think about it, one can configure the POJO generation to use one type for another (in this case, String for ClobType) when generating code.  I must have done that before, and THAT must now be broken.

Comment: Well, it wasn't the reverse engineering that set those fields as Strings.  I must have simply changed them by hand.  Not optimal for the approach I'm taking for my code, but it works.

Comment: Glad it worked out.  It would be nice to actually understand a bit  more how it actually works.  If I come up with better understanding, I'll try to update the answer.